# What would DS and FL stand for in Passenger list

Tags: manifest, abbreviations, documents, queensland

In the Lists of immigrants arriving by immigrant ships at Maryborough QLD, there is a Remarks column. There are numerous DS and FL in this column. What would the DS and FL stand for? They are not short for any full terms in that column.

[image: Passenger List]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Queensland State Archives Brief guide 16 provides some explanations on Immigration Agent records.

Free and assisted passages were granted by the Government to categories of immigrants and their families, which were from time to time required in Queensland. These categories included at various time farmers, farm labourers, vine dressers, labourers, mechanics, female domestic servants and married couples without children.

As the Remarks column included other occupations:

DS would be Domestic Servants and

FL would be Farm Labourers.